# .NET app executed from server stuck on older version

Tags: windows-server-2008, .net, application

I have a .NET application that is installed on a server (has to be that way). On each work station, a disk is mapped and from there they open the app. So the app is only installed in one place in the whole company.

Now one guy is back from holidays and when he opens the app, he's on the same version he was before leaving.

I suspect that the application is download on the local machine before being executed. If you have any idea of how to fix this, I'd appreciate some advice!

I've tested with 3 users and all have the problem on that specific machine.

The first time the app is launched from a station, there's a dealay, that's why I suspect that it is downloaded before being executed.

I tried to fin the app in the Temp folder as well as in the users' files (documents & settings / MyUser) and found nothing.

In the c:/windows/prefetch, I have a MyApp.pf that I deleted, but it hasn't changed anything (and was only 75 kb)

Client OS is Windows XP.

Comment: Get a professional in.

Comment: Hire a system admin for one question? Would be expensive =)

Comment: You do know this site is very specifically for professional sysadmins only right? Pretty much the first line of the FAQ.

Comment: @Chopper3 If the answer to all questions is "Get a pro in", why would this Q&A site exist? Thanks anyway. I'm sys admin for some of my clients, but that's not all I do. Next time I'll right: I'm a professional, but I still have one question.

Comment: Please try to give more details. What exactly is the problem? Any error messages? What have you tried to troubleshoot this? What is the client OS?

Comment: @MichelZ Just added some details

Comment: @user127667 - I was actually being polite, your question seemed like you were out of your depth - hence my suggestion that you needed someone who knew what they were doing. We get a LOT of people who haven't a clue coming here for basic ABC stuff.

Comment: @Chopper3: The guy's performing systems administration tasks, apparently as part of his job responsibilities.  Kinda the definition of "professional sysadmin", innit?

Answer (score 1):

You could try running filemon or another of the tools that show file activity to see where it is pulling the .net app from on the local disk.  That should point you in the direction of what to delete/move/wipe.